# Prove that in $(a+b)^2, a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $ |b|^2 \leq |a|^2$, the real component of the term $2ab$ is at least twice $|b|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I have drafted a proof on this lemma. I wonder if the proof suffices or is there a better way to prove this.

**Lemma 1**

Consider $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and  $|a|^2\geq |b|^2$, the square of sum of $a$ and $b$ produces a cross product term $2ab$ which the real component $\operatorname{RE}\{2ab\}$ is at least twice than $|b|^2$.
$$2|b|^2 \leq \operatorname{RE}\{2ab\}.$$

**Proof**

From $|a|^2 \geq |b|^2$, it follows that
$$            |b|^2 \leq |ab|        $$
Suppose a vector in complex plane with a magnitude $|ab|$ and $\operatorname{RE}\{ab\}$ as its real component. By triangle equality, $|ab|=\operatorname{RE}\{ab\}$. Hence
\begin{align*}
        |b|^2 \leq |ab| = \operatorname{RE}\{ab\} \\
        2|b|^2 \leq \operatorname{RE}\{2ab\}. \blacksquare
    \end{align*}

Comment: Sorry I just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By triangle equality, $|abcd|=$RE$\{abcd\}$

This is not generally true, and the actual assertion is not generally true.  For a counter example to the actual assertion, you can take:

- $a = 5$
- $b = i$

Then Re$(2ab) = 0.$

Forcing $a,b$ to each have non-zero real and imaginary components does not affect the situation.

For example,

$\displaystyle a = 5 + \frac{i}{1000000}$

$\displaystyle b = \frac{1}{1000000} + i.$

---

As for the excerpted clause, at the start of my answer, I do not understand your thinking here, so I can't provide a meaningful refutation of your intended analysis.

---

For what it's worth, if $z = x + iy$ then $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$

Also, if $z,w \in \Bbb{C}$, then $|zw| = |z| \times |w|.$

Comment: In your first example, $a=5, b=i$, I think I should put $2\mathcal{RE}(a)\mathcal{RE}(b)$  so it would be valid.

Comment: @EddyPiedad Really?  If $b = i$ then $\text{Re}(b) = 0.$

Comment: That's right. I think I should consider removing the real component s.t. $2|ab|≥2|b|^2$. BTW, I am working on the energy of signals and their energy exchange.